# Fit setIcon to JButton Array

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton

I know this has been asked a ton of times, but I've searched everywhere and still haven't found an answer. I'm relatively new to Java. I have

```
JButton b[][];
```

Later, I assign `b[3][3].setIcon(path)`. However, the image at `path` is always a small section of the actual image the size of the `JButton`. What I want is to re-size the image to fit the size of the `JButton`. Is there any way to do this? By the way, here's some code that's (I think) is important:

```
int n = 8;
int m = 8;

...

           b = new JButton[n][m];
           setLayout(new GridLayout(n,m));
           for (int y = 0;y<m;y++){
                   for (int x = 0;x<n;x++){
                           b[x][y] = new JButton(" ");
                           b[x][y].addActionListener(this);
                           add(b[x][y]);
                           b[x][y].setEnabled(true);
                   }
           }
```

Comment: That's a really complex subject, you could start having a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070703/how-to-properly-refresh-image-in-jframe/21070799#21070799) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003) for some ideas

Comment: OK, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1):

What you obviously need is a Icon Resizer method, something in the way of what I have provided below:

```
public static Icon resizeIcon(ImageIcon icon, int resizedWidth, int resizedHeight) {
    Image img = icon.getImage();  
    Image img = img.getScaledInstance(resizedWidth, resizedHeight, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);  
    return new ImageIcon(img);
}
```

You can call this method after the image has already been applied to the JButton and **after** it has been added to whatever panel:

```
b[3][3].setIcon(path)
b[3][3].setIcon(resizeIcon((ImageIcon) b[3][3].getIcon(), 
    b[3][3].getWidth() - 15, b[3][3].getHeight() - 15));
```

or you could do it this way:

```
ImageIcon img =  new ImageIcon("MyImage.png");
Icon icn = resizeIcon(img, b[3][3].getWidth() - 15, b[3][3].getHeight() - 15);
b[3][3].setIcon(icn);
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is to re-size the image to fit the size of the JButton.

You can use the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) class.

It will allow you to automatically resize the Icon:

1. to fill the space of the button, or
2. keep the Icon proportion and fill the space of the button

The resizing is done dynamically so you don't need scaled images.

Comment: I used it, but when I did `ImageIcon red = new StretchIcon(path)`, it didn't work...

Comment: Then your path is wrong or you didn't download the class, since it is not part of the JDK.

Comment: The StretchIcon class.

Comment: OK, I did that right, but I did get an error with the package.. could that be why? And if so, how do I get the package?

Comment: @k97513, Then get rid of the package statement. It is not needed unless you want to put the class in a separate package.

Comment: @k97513, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: @k97513, good to know. Next time I'll wait 4 days before I answer.